# Prove the product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

**For this question I am not getting any start .**

Can somebody provide me a hint

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: also you could write $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4}$

Comment: @AlexMathers I don't want to use induction

Comment: @Basti then also itis difficult to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega=\dfrac{1+i}{2}$
\begin{align*}
  \omega^2 &= \frac{1+2i-1}{4} \\
  &= \frac{i}{2} \\
  1+\omega &= \frac{1-\omega^2}{1-\omega} \\
  (1+\omega)(1+\omega^2) &= \frac{1-\omega^4}{1-\omega} \\
  (1+\omega)(1+\omega^2) \ldots (1+\omega^{2^n}) &=
  \frac{1-\omega^{2^{n+1}}}{1-\omega} \\
  &= \left[1-\left( \frac{i}{2} \right)^{2^n} \right]
     \times \frac{1}{1-\omega} \\
  &= \left[ 1-\frac{(-1)^{2^{n-1}}}{2^{2^n}} \right]
     \times \frac{2}{1-i} \\
  &= \left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right)\times \frac{2(1+i)}{1-i^2} \tag{$n\ge 2$} \\
  &= \left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right)(1+i)
\end{align*}